# angularjs $cookieStore size limit

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

I found that angularjs serializes and deserializes when using $cookieStore.put/get and I'm able to put a whole object into it. So what is the size limit? 4kb?

Answer (score 6):

cookie size is 4kb. if your object less than that you will be capable to add the whole object. Just keep in mind that 4kb is for whole cookie including name, expiration and value. But cookie may not be appropriate place to store objects. Please consider to use html5 localStorage except cases when you 100% sure you want it to be in cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. If I go on putting values inside it without "remove" then what will happen after the limit is over. I will get error messages or older cookies will be removed automatically.

Comment: Although, this is not the part of angular behavior, but completely depends on the browser. An old data might be truncated  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595872/what-happens-when-cookies-file-exceeds-maximum-size

Comment: Thanks again.. I think this will be more appropriate for me.. http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html

Comment: Yes. LocalStorage, as I said, is the way to go for the most of cases when you need to store something. Your link is the angular way to work with localStorage